# Java Constructor Initialization?

Tags: java, constructor

Any constructor must explicitly initialize all fields of a class. (Java)

Is this statement true or false? And Can someone please explain why? I do not understand the question.

Answer (score 1):

This statement is false, because **all the fields** of a class are initialized to their default type values. A reference on an object is initialized to `null`, an `int` to `0`, a double to `0.0` etc...

Answer (score 1):

First of, please try it.

**To answer the question:** No. A constructor does not have to initialize all fields.

After the construction of an object all `final` fields must be initialized.

All non-final variables have default variables in Java. [Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)